# Unable to install java module in NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js

I am trying to install java module in my NodeJS project. But i am getting below error unable to figure out what is the problem here. Can anyone guide me on how to go about this. I am using Windows 7 64-bit OS. I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional and MS VC++ Redistributable x86 14.0.xxx15 installed in my PC.

I am using python2.7, jdk 1.8.0_101 (oracle jdk).

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install java

Standard error:
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 2148734720
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\SmartBin\Server\node_modules\java
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "java"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! java@0.8.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.8.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the java package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs java
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls java
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\SmartBin\Server\npm-debug.log


Standard output:

> java@0.8.0 install C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\SmartBin\Server\node_modules\java
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\SmartBin\Server\node_modules\java>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild ) 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: have you got `the latest version of node.js and npm installed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with node-gyp command.
Try installing the latest version of node-gyp.
First go to the location where your node.exe is installed. To find that in your command prompt run:

```
$where node
```

Now cd to the directory that node.exe is contained in, and with node_modules\npm at the end. i.e.

```
$ cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm"
```

Now you can finally run:

```
$ npm install -g node-gyp@latest
```

After this try again to run npm java to install java modules.
I hope this helps :)
Just in case before running above commands install latest version of node by doing cd to the location where node is installed and run 
:(Note-Open a Command Prompt as administrator for this)

```
npm install npm@latest
```

Comment: tried your suggestion but i am still getting same error.

Comment: Go to this link and follow the steps. It might help:[link](http://blog.jimdhughes.com/2015/04/09/perils-with-node-gyp-and-windows-development/)

Comment: Tried your latest suggestion and help me in resolving the issue. Thank you.